# Python syntax: Compare datetime fields and update only if enough time has passed

Tags: python, datetime

New to Python, and I want do something like this:

```
now = datetime.now()

if now - myClass.last_updated_date >= 3 min:
    myClass.update()
```

Meaning, if myClass hasn't been updated in the last 3 minutes, update it now.

last_updated_date is a datetime value as well.

How can I get the difference between these two datetime values in terms of minutes or seconds?

Comment: This question shows some lack of effort. try `type(now - myClass.last_updated_date)`, then read the appropriate documentation

Answer (score 1):

Just subtracting datetime objects will give you a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which are directly comparable with one another:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: old = datetime.datetime.now()

In [3]: new = datetime.datetime.now()

In [4]: new - old
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(0, 6, 502461)

In [5]: new - old > datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
Out[5]: False

In [6]: new - old > datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)
Out[6]: True
```

This is explained very clearly on the [`datetime` documentation page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for illustrating it so simply! Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
delta = now - myClass.last_updated_date
minutes = delta.minutes
seconds = delta.seconds
type(delta) #=> <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html for more info.